# Execute command when urxvt gains/loses focus

Tags: focus, urxvt, window-focus

I would like to notify programs running in urxvt whenever they (meaning the urxvt window they are running in) gained or lost focus. Is this possible? If there is a standard solution for this, I'm happy to adopt this.

Comment: Compiz may have something for this, if applicable. // otherwise you would need something that looks at the various x11 events and reacts to selected messages. // your window manager should perhaps the easiest/first port of call, but would be WM specific.